# Do applicants who are exempted from paying application fees get any other benefits

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application, united-states

Several universities waive graduate application fees for certain applicants who participated in a specific program or belong to a certain organization. My question is: do these applicants get any other benefits or considerations in the application process, or is the application fee exemption the end of the story?

Example of one of the universities that offers this:
http://grad.berkeley.edu/admissions/apply/fee-waiver/

Comment: Like what other considerations are you thinking of?  The only thing that comes to mind to me would be post-acceptance at the undergrad level.  There are often programs that take place in the summer before the freshman year, to get students acclimated.

Comment: Roughly: It would be the end of the story...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've served on a doctoral admissions committee and we were not made aware of these fee waivers or special organization ties unless the individual directly wrote about them in their statements of purpose or resumes.